# Swift & Cordova Inheritance Two Class

Tags: objective-c, swift, cordova, class, inheritance

Now days, I want to create Swift Cordova plugin.

I have a One object.c Library. (.h, .m file)

Then I Want to make a swift class for cordova plugin.

it must inherit by CDVPlugin. but when swift class inherit by CDVPlugin,

then i can't inherit My object.c Library.

Because of, Multiple inheritance is not supported in swift.

How Can I Do?

> Cordova Plugin is here

https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVPlugin.h

https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVPlugin.m

My Object.c Library is here

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Commucation.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

@protocol BodySDKDelegate
- (void) Evt_StatusLog:(NSString*)log Status:(LogStatus)status;
- (void) Evt_DetailLog:(NSString*)log Status:(LogStatus)status;
- (void) Evt_Connect;
- (void) Evt_DisConnect;
- (void) Evt_StopScan;
- (void) Evt_BLEUpdateState:(Boolean)isPaired;
- (void) Evt_SendFrame:(NSData*) data;
@end

@interface BLEController : UIViewController <CBCentralManagerDelegate,      UARTPeripheralDelegate>
{
     Boolean SDK_bDisconnect; // disconnect flag
     Boolean SDK_bReceviedAK;
}

@property CBPeripheral*         SDK_discovered_peripheral;
@property UARTPeripheral*       SDK_currentPeripheral;
@property ConnectionState       SDK_state;
@property CBCentralManager*     SDK_cm;
@property id<BodySDKDelegate> SDK_delegate;

- (void) SDK_StopScan;
- (void) SDK_ScanDevice:    (Boolean)init;
- (void) SDK_InitVariable:  (double)_height Weight:(double)_weight Age:    (int)_age Gender:(NSString*)_Gender delegate:(id<BodySDKDelegate>) delegate;
- (void) SDK_fncSendCommand:(unsigned char)cmd1 cmd2:(unsigned char)cmd2 data:(NSData *)data;
- (void) SDK_SetDeviceName: (NSString*) Name;
- (void) SDK_RemoveDevice;
-(Boolean) SDK_CheckPreviousDevice;

@end
```

Comment: Do you want your plugin to conform to the `InBodySDKDelegate` protocol? I don't think a Cordova plugin can be a view controller subclass, like `BLEController`.

Comment: I want to use CordovaPlugin function and InbodySDK Function and variable both.